# without document.ready function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

is document.ready really necessary. This question has been asked countless time.

This code snippet is with document.ready and works perfectly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
    alert("You entered p1!");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="p1">Enter this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

However, if i were to replace the script tag contents with this.

```
  $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
    alert("You entered p1!");
  });
```

It no longer works. However, if the argument was that the document is not ready upon mouse enter. I have waited for a few mins before trying and it still does not work. Is there something i am missing out

Comment: What do you mean by "I have waited for a few mins before trying"? How did you do that?

Comment: *"I have waited for a few mins before trying and it still does not work."* This is not how it works :) When you execute this code `$("#p1")` the DOM tree is not yet loaded so there is no `<p id="p1">` element. With DOMContentLoaded event you make sure the code will execute as soon as DOM loading complete.

Comment: *document is not ready upon mouse enter*: where did you get that argument from? The document is not ready when the javascript engine encounters that line in code, so it doesn't find `p`.

Comment: domready is necessary to wait the DOM being loaded before attach any event handler; works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/vyu76y8k/

Comment: add script to the bottom of page before body tag ends, it will work.

Comment: Notice another important functionality of `$(document).ready()`, it helps you to avoid global variables effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can put that script in the *bottom* of `body` tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p id="p1">Enter this paragraph.</p>
  <script>
    $("#p1").mouseenter(function() {
      alert("You entered p1!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

---

Q: Why `$("#p1").mouseenter()` does not work in the `head` tag and even after a while waiting?

A: `$("#p1")` is a *function* and whenever is called, it looks up whole DOM tree for an element with ID `p1` and *register* an event listener for it, so when the DOM is still being loaded, it cannot find such element and obviously cannot register any event listener for it. hence when you enter the mouse over this element after a while, there is no event listener assigned to this element.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
$("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
    alert("You entered p1!");
});
```

Is an event handler tied to a DOM element, `#p1`.  The `$(document).ready()` handler ensures that all DOM elements are loaded before attempting to execute any code within the handler.  If the element with `id="p1"` does not exist when the `mouseenter` event handler tied to it is created, the `mouseenter` event handler will handle nothing, no matter how long you wait.

Always make sure that elements exist before you tie event handlers to them.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that when DOM is read it interprets your scripts along the way. And if you want to add a handler to an element that has not yet been loaded by browser. Browser will ignore it.
Here you got 3 choces:

- place JS code inside a document.ready function - you are using it:)
- place all JS code at the bottom of DOM (just before end body tag) -this can also boost your performance a bit
- use defer attribute to your script tags, this will tell your browser, that it should start executing JS code after the DOM is loaded.

About defer attribute:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Answer (score 1):

Well , All you need to know is that your element should be in the DOM prior using any jquery selector. i.e. If you place your script tag below your element then there is not need of use ready event. The browser reads the html from top to bottom so , Once it encounter your script tag , code inside that tag executes immediately and start finding the element placed in the jquery selectors.